# Accuracy of data set

Tags: matlab, statistics, data-analysis

I am doing a study on the performance of Aquifer thermal energy storage systems. During this study, I get results with consist of a normal distribution around a mean. What can I now say about the accuracy of my mean? is there a statistical methode for this? Take in mind that the result is dependent on multiple variables that explain the spread.

I first looked at a standard deviation but this results in use error margins. 
I think it is more accurate as it is known that the measurement devices have an accuracy of about 2.

The result can, for example, have an average of 9 with a spread around it:
[image: The result can, for example, have an average of 9 with a spread around it]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO, this doesnt seem to be a question about programming but rather of statistical nature. You should ask it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: Thanks, I Didn't know of this site :)

Comment: voted to close as OP asked the question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430992/accuracy-of-the-mean

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hans! How are you doing? Let's see if I can give you a hand

> What can I now say about the accuracy of my mean? is there a statistical methode for this?
>   What you'd want to do next is to estabilish a confidence interval around your mean, usually with a 95% confidence level
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval
>   (I don't remember the exact mathematics around its calculation but it's simple enough)

Unlike with other estimators, you cannot derive a "p-value" about a mean. A mean of a sample is a mean of a sample, it's the most accurate prediction of itself. What you do is estabilish a confidence interval and say: "With a 95% confidence, I can say that the 100% accurate result is between x1 and x2"

Cheers!